# How to compare two columns in csv and print out missing rows in pandas, python?

Tags: python, pandas

Actually I'm stuck because I don't know why this code doesn't work.
I have two files with identical column names, however I want to extract cells from 'x' column that are in aaa.csv and are not in template csv file.
I'm using pandas lib.

My code:

```
template = pd.read_csv(template_file, sep=';', skiprows=skipped_rows, header = 1)
x_column_template = template['x']

csv_sheet= = pd.read_csv("aaa.csv", skiprows=skipped_rows, header = 1)
x_column = csv_sheets['x']


with open('diff.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    for line in x_column:
        if line not in x_column_template:
            outFile.write(str(line)+"\n")
```

The problem is that in diff.csv I keep getting **all** values from aaa.csv, not only values that are missing in template.

Example csv files (in my case these files have much more columns, but I'm comparing the same column in two files):

[image: example]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please add a minimal repriducable example? It will ve easier to for people to help you.

Comment: @Charalamm works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: for me your code works fine for some reason, when i use ints as dataframe calues but not when i am using strings. surly there is a problem with dtypes